# How do i add Subclasses data to my array in c#

Tags: c#

For example, I have a public class `Vehicles` that inherits from  `MobileObjects`. That `Vehicles` class has `10meters`, `23meters`, `12meters`  as data.

How would I add that info to this array??

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
    MobileObjects[] array = new MobileObjects[3];

    MobileObjects mob = new MobileObjects();
    mob.setName("Jawaharal");
    mob.setPosition();
    mob.getID();
    array[0] = mob;

    MobileObjects mob1 = new MobileObjects();
    mob1.setName("Willow");
    mob1.setPosition();
    array[1] = mob1;

    MobileObjects mob2 = new MobileObjects();
    mob2.setName("Indira");
    mob2.setPosition();
    array[2] = mob2;

    foreach (MobileObjects host in array) {
        Console.WriteLine("Name : " + host.Name + " ");
        Console.WriteLine("ID   : " + host.id);
        Console.WriteLine("Position: " +
            host.Position[0] + " " +
            host.Position[1] + " " +
            host.Position[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, the class Vehicle is an extension of MobileObjects?

Comment: @LeeToffolo yes its an extension

Comment: You should show the relevant parts of the classes. Also, what do you mean by *"that Vehicles class had lets say 10meters ,23meters ,12meters as data"*? Does this data belong to a collection property of the `Vehicle` class?

Comment: @RufusL yes it belongs to the Vehicle class

Comment: Just a point on code style - usually, a class name is singular, not plural. When you use the `new` keyword, you are making a new `Vehicle`, not a `Vehicles`.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what problem you are running into when you add a `Vehicle` to the `MobileObjects[] array` (which you haven't shown). Can you please describe the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your Vehicle instance to a MobileObject, and then add it to the array. (this is not a necessary cast in all cases, but may be what you need in your situation depending on the properties of both your Vehicle and MobileObjects classes)

```
Vehicle veh1 = new Vehicle();
/// Add veh1 parameters
array[3] = (MobileObjects)veh1;
```

Note: Since you casted your instance to its base class, you should now only be able to access the shared parameters when viewing the array[3] item.

Comment: You don't need to cast it if `Vehicle : MobileObjects`.

Comment: how would i print the data afterwards?

Comment: @Rufus L yeah, I guess I dont, I was assumming a lot, and thought this would be the safest answer (given what we know) I may edit or delete once they get back to use with weiter or not the property is a part of the base class

Comment: @Momo ,you would print it like your other array objects. Your foreach loop will do the trick without any editing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to use a C# generic collection like Array or List and auto properties.

You can find information about collections here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections

Information about auto-properties is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

---

It seems you want to stick to using getters and setters though. In keeping with your current conventions, you could use a SetAt method.

```
array[0].SetPositionAt(0, 10);
array[0].SetPositionAt(1, 23);
```

However to do this, you would need to allocate space inside your MobileObject.

```
public class MobileObject 
{
    private int[] _position;

    public MobileObject() 
    {
        Position = new int[3]; 
    }

    public void SetPositionAt(int idx, int value) 
    {
        _position[idx] = value;
    }

    public int GetPositionAt(int idx)
    {
        return _position[idx];
    }
}
```

You would then get the information like this:

```
host.GetPositionAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first restate what I *think* you're asking:

> How can I tell if an object in my array is of the `baseClass` type or of a `derivedClass` type, so that I can show the properties for the `derivedClass` when applicable?

If this is correct, one way to do this is to use the `is` keyword to check if the current item is a specific type, and the `as` keyword to get an object of that type (with the extra properties):

```
if (someArrayItem is DerivedClass)
{
    DerivedClass itemAsDerived = someArrayItem as DerivedClass;

    Console.WriteLine(itemAsDerived.SomeDerivedProperty);
}
```

Here's a way to do it with some simple example (since you have not provided your classes to use, I will create my own here, where we have a common base class `Vehicle`, and two derived classes that have their own unique properties):

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int SeatCount { get; set; }
}

public class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public double CargoCapacity { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can add a mix of these items to a `List<Vehicle>`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>
    {
        new Vehicle {Name = "Vehicle", Color = Color.Blue},
        new Truck {Name = "Pickup Truck", Color = Color.Red, CargoCapacity = 12.4},
        new Car {Name = "SUV", Color= Color.Purple, SeatCount = 7}
    };

    foreach (Vehicle vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        Console.Write("This item is a: " + vehicle.Color.Name + " " + vehicle.Name);

        if (vehicle is Truck)
        {
            // It's a truck so create a truck from it and show the truck properties
            Truck truck = vehicle as Truck;

            Console.Write(" with cargo capacity of " + truck.CargoCapacity +
                          " square feet.");
        }
        else if (vehicle is Car)
        {
            // It's a car so create a car from it and show the car properties
            Car car = vehicle as Car;

            Console.Write(" with seating for " + car.SeatCount + " people");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your description is kind of difficult to know what do you need. I hope I understood it well.

Firstly - As sugessted in other answers most of the time using List is better than array.

Here is a code:

```
using System;

namespace NamedTuple
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MobileObject[] mobileObjects = new MobileObject[3];
            // insert MobileObject
            MobileObject mob1 = new MobileObject()
            {
                Name = "Jawahara",
                Position = (12, 15),
                Id = 123456
            };
            mobileObjects[0] = mob1;

            //Insert Vehicle
            Vehicle veh = new Vehicle()
            {
                Name = "Willow",
                Position = (14, 13),
                Id = 6549879,
                Length = 23
            };
            mobileObjects[1] = veh;

            //Insert another vehicle
            mobileObjects[2] = new Vehicle()
            {
                Name = "Indira",
                Position = (14, 13),
                Id = 885298451,
                Length = 12
            };

            foreach (var mobileObject in mobileObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name: {mobileObject.Name}, " +
                    $"Position: {mobileObject.Position.X };{mobileObject.Position.Y}, " +
                    $"Id: {mobileObject.Id}");

                if(mobileObject is Vehicle)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Length: {((Vehicle)mobileObject).Length}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MobileObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public (int X, int Y) Position { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vehicle : MobileObject
    {
        public int Length { get; set; }
    }
}
```